# Automatic data entry to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a code for the command button "Add Entry" that will add the entered data in the cells to a table in another sheet.|

The table has the same headers as mentioned in the image.
[image]

I have created the code for adding data entry. Thanks!

Comment: Have you written any code yet ?

Comment: I have written the code for selecting the data from the cells, but I am stuck as I don't know how to add this data to a table and then have the later data added to a row below it and so on.

Comment: Use offset to get to new row, and use `endxlDown` to find last used row.

Comment: Post the code and explain the problem you are having with it. Just explaining the requirement is not enough. Read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 name = Range("D8").Value
  des = Range("D10").Value
  veh = Range("D12").Value
  start = Range("D14").Value
  finish = Range("D16").Value

  Sheets("Master Sheet").Select

  LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Range("A" & LR).Offset(1, 0).Select

  i = ActiveCell.Row
  Cells(i, 1).Formula = start
  Cells(i, 2).Formula = finish
  Cells(i, 3).Formula = name
  Cells(i, 4).Formula = des
  Cells(i, 5).Formula = veh
```

You will have entry added to new row every time. I assumed your sheet name as master sheet, where the data is going. Also you can name the header however you like.